# PHP Function printing before HTML markup

Tags: php, html

I have quite the peculiar problem... I've got a working PHP function, as shown below, which fetches a users' score and outputs some information based on that score (it's not optimized yet).

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, when I put it in my code, it's not actually being rendered inside the HTML markup/position I want it to be rendered in - instead, it's being rendered at the top of the page, and a search has not yielded any results.

The code simplified is:

```
<?php
require('displayCodes.php');
displayCodesMain(1);
?>
```

The `displayCodesMain` code:

```
<?php
function displayCodesMain($page){ 
    if($page == 1){?>
<table class="friendcodes">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Friend Code</th>
        <th>Affinity</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
<?php
        $plisting = file_get_contents('plist.txt');
        $plist = explode(' ', $plisting, 4);
        require_once('vote.php');
        array_pop($plist);
        foreach($plist as $item) {
            $item = explode(':', $item);
            echo '<tr class="fc_premium">';
            $item[3] = substr($item[3], 0, 3) . '-' . substr($item[3], 3, 7);
            $item[1] = str_replace('&', ' ', $item[1]);
            echo '<td>' . $item[1] . '</td><td>' . $item[3] . '</td><td style="text-transform:capitalize;">' . $item[4] . '</td><td>' . $item[5] . '</td><td> '. displayRating(1)
.' </td>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
        }    
        echo '</table>';
    }
} // End of the function
?>
```

The actual function itself:

```
<?php
function displayRating($id){
    if(isset($id)){
        require_once('medoo.min.php');
        // Start up the D.B. Connection
        // Removed some DB setup code here...
        $phrase = '<div class="bc"><div data-hint="%1$s" class="hint--right vote %2$s"></div></div>';
        if($vScore == 0){
            printf($phrase, 'Neutral Score', 'v_equal');
            return;
        } elseif ($vScore > 0){
            // Positive Here
            switch($vScore){
                case 1:
                    printf($phrase, '1 Like', 'v_p1 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf($phrase, '2 Likes', 'v_p2 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf($phrase, '3 Likes', 'v_p3 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf($phrase, '4 Likes', 'v_p4 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf($phrase, '5 Likes', 'v_p5 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf($phrase, '6 Likes', 'v_p6 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf($phrase, '7 Likes', 'v_p7 hint--success');
                    break;
                default:
                    printf($phrase, $vScore . ' Likes', 'v_p7 hint-success');
                    break;
            }
        } elseif ($vScore < 0){
            // Negative Here
            switch($vScore){
                case -1:
                    printf($phrase, '1 Dislike', 'v_m1 hint--error');
                    break;
                default:
                    if($vScore < -7){ $vClass = 7; } else { $vClass = abs($vScore); }
                    printf($phrase, abs($vScore) . ' Dislikes', 'v_m' . $vClass . ' hint--error');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

I've even put in a static variable for the function in the first `foreach` statement, yet, I still have no luck in getting it to display in the proper place.

I am currently unable to gain access to my php.ini, and `phpinfo()` appears to be disabled for security reasons. I will get back to you guys after I find out my info from my host.

Comment: This may have something to do with output buffering. I had a similar problem (though it was in WordPress, it was doing the same thing). I got an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467912/php-not-echoing-in-the-right-place , which suggested some edits for .htaccess and php.ini . Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Is the table what you want to have displayed below your `<h3>`?

Comment: FWIW - looking at your test page - your code is generating broken HTML. It's creating `<div>` elements in the `<tr>` when, I guess, they should be in the `<td>` elements.

Comment: The table is not below the <h3>, However the circles should be appearing in the last column of the table row, but they are not.

Comment: Should I be 'returning' the values from my function in some other manner? This might explain the incredibly odd manner that it's acting in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main program, you're using `echo` to output the return value of `displayRating()`, but it doesn't return anything. Instead, `displayRating()` is **also using `echo`**. This is why your output appears out of order.

Turn this:

```
echo /* ... */ '</td><td> '. displayRating(1) .' </td>';
```

into:

```
echo /* ... */ '</td><td> ';
displayRating(1);
echo ' </td>';
```

**or** build and return a string from  `displayRating()`.